# remove file from android

Tags: android, file, audio

I tried code from this [record sound](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html). I see that I can release sound using the following code:

```
private void stopPlaying() {  
    mPlayer.release();  
    mPlayer = null;  
}
```

The problem is that I want to release the sound and delete the recorded file. if only use this code I still have the sound file on mFileName with file name is audiorecordtest.3gp.

Anyone know how to delete this file so I can save memory on my phone ?

Comment: have you try this my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this code,

```
  File f1 = new File(mFileName);
  boolean success = f1.delete();
  if (!success){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  else
  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```